# In a bash script, how can I go to a directory whose name is stored in a variable?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, directory

I'm doing a FileCreator script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Welcome to the file creator! Please type the directory name:"
read dirName

mkdir $dirName

#Now I want to change directory to that new $dirName that will be run from Terminal.
```

My question is now, how to change the path to this new directory `dirName` that is visible on Terminal. So, at the end, path should be: `/home/my_user_name/SCRIPTS/dirName` when I run this script ...

Please, just a suggestion? :)

Comment: `cd $dirName`, surely?

Comment: Yes, but if I add this `cd $dirName` and run from Terminal this script, it isn't at this directory ... I tried.

Comment: @andrejbenedičič Ah, I see. You want the *calling shell* to be in that directory, even after the script is finished running. I'll expand my answer.

Comment: Because when you exit the script, the directory will change back to where it was before. It's a feature....

Comment: Aha. So if I want to go to that directory after running the script, I still need to run `cd /name_of_the_wanted_directory` later on Terminal? So it won't be automatically located at new directory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The `cd` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)) changes [what directory you are in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). Run `help cd` for details.

If `dirName` is a shell [variable](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-5.html) that contains the name of the directory you want to go to, then

```
cd -- "$dirName"
```

will go there. For example, if you start out in `/home/my_user_name/SCRIPTS` and the variable `dirName` contains the text `foo`, then that command brings you to `/home/my_user_name/SCRIPTS/foo`.

If you always want `dirName` to be interpreted as a [relative path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths) in `/home/my_user_name/SCRIPTS`, regardless of where the user runs your script from, then use:

```
cd -- "/home/my_user_name/SCRIPTS/$dirName"
```

You may have noticed [the leading `--` argument and the use of quotation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters):

- In a script, when passing user input as [arguments](http://foldoc.org/argument) to a command that accepts [options](http://foldoc.org/option) starting with `-` or `--`, it's usually a good idea to pass [the `--` option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean-also-known-as-bare-double-dash) first. Most commands that accept filename arguments support this syntax (you should always check, though). It means that all subsequent arguments are to be interpreted as filenames rather than as options.

  To understand this, try running `ls -l`, and try running `ls -- -l`. You don't usually need to use the `--` argument when you're typing commands manually. But in a script that passes the value of unsanitized input to a command, it's frequently used.
- In both commands, I have used [double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html#Double-Quotes) (`"` `"`). This is usually what you want when expanding a variable that contains a filename.

  Like if you used no quotes at all, but unlike [single quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html#Single-Quotes) (`'` `'`), double quotes permit [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). So they don't prevent `$dirName` from being expanded to the value that was assigned to it by the `read` command. However, unlike not using quotes at all, but like single quotes, double quotes prevent [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html#Word-Splitting). That way, if the variable contains whitespace characters (or [characters present in `IFS`](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/$IFS), [if that has been set](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97481/ifs-null-is-not-the-same-as-unset-ifs)), it will still work properly.

  See also [3.1.2 Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting) in the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).

I recommend also using double-quotes in your `mkdir` commmand, and probably also `--`:

```
mkdir -- "$dirName"
```

---

Note, however, that changing the current directory in a shell script does not cause [the *calling* process](http://foldoc.org/parent%20process)'s current directory to be changed. This is by design (and holds in most, if not all, operating systems, including Windows). When a program runs another program, it does not expect *its own* current directory to be changed.

Every program has its own [environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable), and its own current directory. When you start a new program, it inherits this from the program that started it, but it has its own copy. When a [child process](http://foldoc.org/child%20process) changes its current directory, that is *not* reflected in the parent process.

Often, when you want to change directory for the caller, the correct approach is to reconsider your design. Do you really need this?

Essentially the only situation where it is reasonable to change directory for the caller is when your script is really just a list of commands that would be just as well be run directly by the caller. When that is the case, [you can *source* the script instead of running it](https://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-and-sourcing-a-bash-scrip). For example, suppose you are currently running your script with the command:

```
./my_script
```

Then you can instead *source* it with:

```
. ./my_script
```

This alternative syntax is also supported:

```
source ./my_script
```

[The Bash shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) supports both the `.` and `source` [builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands), and they are equivalent. (Run `help .` or `help source` for details.)

This causes all the commands in your script [to be run in the current shell](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x237.html), rather than in a new shell (which is what happens when you actually *run* a shell script).

Comment: woooooow, thank you for the nice explanation. So, then the path it won't be automatically in `dirName` after executing this script? :D

Comment: @andrejbenedičič Yes, when you run a script (`./my_script`) rather than sourcing it (`. ./my_script`), the parent shell does not have any of its own variables changed. However, `cd` in shell scripts is still frequently useful (and is even often useful *because* one can change directory in the script without affecting the caller). For example, if you plan to expand your script with code that creates a file in the directory you've `cd`'d to (I'm just guessing, based on the way you described what you were trying to do), then that should work fine.

Comment: I run this script as `. WorkingWithFiles.sh` and it works. Thank you, @EliahKagan.